# What this type of bolt is called and how I can remove it?

Tags: bolts

I don’t have idea how to remove this bolt.I can spin it but it just keep spinnig.[image]

Comment: That is a rivet, not a bolt.

Comment: Yup, rivet. You will need to drill through it or chisel off either the peened over top or bottom.

Answer (score 2):

### It's a rivet.

Not a bolt at all.

You either drill it out if you can stop it spinning (typically from the other side if accessible,) or grind it off if you can't stop it spinning. If you don't own a grinder you can also remove it with a cold chisel and a hammer by cutting off the raised rim from several directions.